# Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.quartz

Tags: jboss, quartz-scheduler, wildfly-12

I am adding quartz-2.2.1 scheduler to my application and on deploying it on WildFly 12 the below error is thrown.

```
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.quartz
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1221)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1577)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1605)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:296)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:280)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:68)
    ... 8 more
```

This is for WildFly 12 application server. Earlier my application was on Jboss6 with quartz-1.8.3 and it's working fine. Now I am trying to upgrade the application server.

Below are the pom.xml dependency code and jboss-deployment-structure.xml under WEB-INF.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.quartz" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I want to know if I am missing something so that I am getting this error.

Comment: Did you install it as a module or are you putting the dependencies in your deployment?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, I had directory names mismatch and on correcting them, it started working.

Comment: @santoshM  please  can you post the solution

Comment: @NeptuneZ : as you see my comment above, I had directory names mismatch so could not start it.